# Associate posts to tags with help of Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How to associate blog posts with tags in Spark?

```
val posts = Seq("BMW is a good car", 
"AUDI beats Tesla on speed race", 
"BMW exposes its new vehicle at Montreal", 
"Mercedes introduces beast offroad track")

val rdd = sc.makeRDD(posts)

val tags = Seq("BMW", "AUDI", "Mercedes")
```

So based on data above I want to get new `RDD[(String, Iterable[String]]`:

("BMW", Iterable("BMW is a good car", "BMW exposes its new vehicle at Montreal")

("AUDI", Iterable("AUDI beats Tesla on speed race"))

("Mercedes", Iterable("Mercedes introduces beast offroad track"))

Any ideas how it could be done?

Comment: In simplest form, 

rdd.filter( row => row.contains("BMW"))
.map(line => ("BMW",line))
.groupByKey()
.collect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// broadcast the tags
val tags_broadcast = sc.broadcast(tags)

// extract the tags each string contains in the rdd, make a pair rdd where the first element 
// is the tag and second element is the string, then call groupByKey method
rdd.flatMap(s => tags_broadcast.value.filter(s.contains(_)).map((_, s))).groupByKey.collect

// res110: Array[(String, Iterable[String])] = Array((AUDI,CompactBuffer(AUDI beats Tesla on speed race)), (BMW,CompactBuffer(BMW is a good car, BMW exposes its new vehicle at Montreal)), (Mercedes,CompactBuffer(Mercedes introduces beast offroad track)))
```